# Subscriber gets older timestamped messages

Tags: ros, rospy, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

2 different nodes are listening to a msg with the same `topic`. 1 node (written in `C++`) gets the msg and print its content in an expected, minimum delay. But the other (`python`) node shows the older content and I have no idea why this delay occurs. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Codes (partial, they show where I compare the values):

- [Successful listener (`C++`)](http://pastebin.com/cycTXPTT)
- [Unsuccessful listener (`python`) subclass](http://pastebin.com/76G26sEj)
- [Unsuccessful listener (`python`) parent class](http://pastebin.com/LFXW2Ybt)

Coincident or not, the difference is the language (C++ vs Python), and extension (Codes in python is separated into parent and sub class). But I don't know if these factors matter (and hopefully they do not).

All nodes run on the same machine (Ubuntu 11.04, `electric`, Intel i7 quad).

---

**Update** 11/2/11) I'm now comparing `timestamp` and approx. 30 seconds after starting program, the difference of timestamps from both nodes are 8 ROS seconds.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11766/subscriber-gets-older-timestamped-messages/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved by myself - changing subscriber's `queue_size` works out for me. Using the code example on my environment I described in the question, I increased it from 1 to 5 in the problematic code (the one in python). Btw the `queue_size` in the publisher is not showing influence here.

PS. However I still don't get why...I've read documents including [this QA](http://answers.ros.org/question/500/how-does-second-term-of-advertise?answer=886#886) though. Is my understanding below correct...? I'll give a vote if someone corrects it.

> Increasing `queue_size` means the number of msgs processed in one callback increases, and that number could be greater than calling callback during exactly same length of period.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-02**:
@tfoote thank you, that makes perfect sense to me. Now I feel this queuing architecture might not be ROS specific but instead more common in general distributed system, and also suppose that could be because the documents out there don't explain detail.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-02**:
All messages being received are put into a queue.  When this queue has data in it, your callbacks will be called.  However if data comes in faster than your callback executes, the queue will fill up.  It looks like you had your queue length set to 1000.  Meaning you could be 1000 messages behind.